# replace in text with a var with some new lines

Tags: linux, shell

I have a var **$MY_VAR** which contains some new lines:

```
      hostAliases:
      - ip: "?.?.?.?"
        hostnames:
        - "m-0.mongodb-service.default.svc.cluster.local"
      - ip: "?.?.?.?"
        hostnames:
        - "m-1.mongodb-service.default.svc.cluster.local"
      - ip: "?.?.?.?"
        hostnames:
        - "m-2.mongodb-service.default.svc.cluster.local"
      - ip: "?.?.?.?"
        hostnames:
        - "m-3.mongodb-service.default.svc.cluster.local"
```

And a file **my_file.txt** with a value that has to be replaced:

```
some indented content ...
@@MY_VALUE@@
some indented content ...
```

I try to replace it using:

```
sed -i 's,@@MY_VALUE@@,'"$MY_VAR"',g' my_file.txt
```

That results into the following error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 36: unterminated `s' command
```

Comment: hum that's seems to have nothing to do with my problem.

Comment: I try to replace the value @@MY_VALUE@@ into the file my_file.txt with the value of $MY_VAR. (-i means in place)

Comment: I have the content into a file and fill a var using MY_VAR=$(cat content.txt)

Comment: Did you properly escape the special characters?

Comment: Did you try using double quotes `sed -i "s,@@MY_VALUE@@,$MY_VAR,g" my_file.txt`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a totally different solution by removing the value to replace and split my file into two parts: my_file_part1.txt and my_file_part2.txt which are respectively the part before the variable and the part after the variable.

```
touch my_file.txt
cat my_file_part1.txt >> my_file.txt
echo "$MY_VAR" >> my_file.txt
cat my_file_part2.txt >> my_file.txt
```

Comment: Don't post this as answer. Where is `my_file_part1.txt` coming from? Where is split and where is `@@MY_VALUE@@`.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to do:

```
MY_VAR=$(cat content.txt)
```

To first read file content into a variable and then replace a text in second file with this variable's content.

You may use this `sed` to do this in single step:

```
sed '/@@MY_VALUE@@/{s///;
r content.txt
}' my_file.txt
```

some indented content ...

```
some indented content ...

      hostAliases:
      - ip: "?.?.?.?"
        hostnames:
        - "m-0.mongodb-service.default.svc.cluster.local"
      - ip: "?.?.?.?"
        hostnames:
        - "m-1.mongodb-service.default.svc.cluster.local"
      - ip: "?.?.?.?"
        hostnames:
        - "m-2.mongodb-service.default.svc.cluster.local"
      - ip: "?.?.?.?"
        hostnames:
        - "m-3.mongodb-service.default.svc.cluster.local"
some indented content ...
```

---

**Update:**

You may use this `awk` to replace a pattern with a multiline variable:

```
awk -v var="$var" '/@@MY_VALUE@@/{$0 = var} 1' my_file.txt
```

To save changes inline use this option if using `gnu awl`:

```
awk -i inplace -v var="$var" '/@@MY_VALUE@@/{$0 = var} 1' my_file.txt
```

If not using `gnu awk` then use:

```
awk -v var="$var" '/@@MY_VALUE@@/{$0 = var} 1' my_file.txt >> $$.tmp &&
mv $$.tmp my_file.txt
```

Comment: Thank you but the content of the file is stored on GitLab CI variable. It isn't possible to do what you wrote.

Comment: Don't understand what you mean by `GitLab CI variable`. But you wrote that you're doing  `MY_VAR=$(cat content.txt)` and answer is based on that.

Comment: Also see an `awk` variant

Answer (score 0):

Here's an easier way to reproduce your problem:

```
sed -e 's/foo/hello
world/'
```

Instead of replacing `foo` with two lines, it shows `` sed: -e expression #1, char 11: unterminated `s' command ``

This is because linefeeds end the command. You have to escape them with backslashes:

```
sed -e 's/foo/hello\
world/'
```

You can do this in your variable with Bash's parameter expansion (`${var//search/replace}`):

```
sed "s/@@MY_VALUE@@/${var//$'\n'/$'\\\n'}/"
```